# Postgresql select from table that contains array as many rows as in the aray

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a problem in a select request with Postgesql
I have a table

```
+-------------------+-----+
|      array        |value|
+-------------------+-----+
|["1","k"]          |   35|
+-------------------+-----+
|["125","15l","1m"] |   40|
+-------------------+-----+
```

and what I want:

```
+-------------------+-----+
|      array        |value|
+-------------------+-----+
|   "1"             |   35|
+-------------------+-----+
|   "k"             |   35|
+-------------------+-----+
|   "125"           |   40|
+-------------------+-----+
|   "15l"           |   40|
+-------------------+-----+
|   "1m"            |   40|
+-------------------+-----+
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `unnest`:

```
select unnest(array), value
from table_name;
```

P.S.: I assume for `"k"`, the value is supposed to be 35.

Comment: @sr9419 no problem, consider upvoting;>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unnest()`:

```
edb=# CREATE TABLE mt (a text[], val int);
CREATE TABLE
edb=# INSERT INTO mt VALUES (array['1','k'],35);
INSERT 0 1
edb=# INSERT INTO mt VALUES (array['125','151','1m'],40);
INSERT 0 1
edb=# SELECT unnest(a),val FROM mt;
 unnest | val 
--------+-----
 1      |  35
 k      |  35
 125    |  40
 151    |  40
 1m     |  40
(5 rows)
```